# Not able to read the file name from the http request header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

I'm not able to read the file name as well as other values that come from the client. I'm using HttpWebRequest to send Multi part data to the server. My client side code looks like so:

```
public string upload(string file, string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest requestToServer = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);


        // Define a boundary string
        string boundaryString = "----";

        // Turn off the buffering of data to be written, to prevent
        // OutOfMemoryException when sending data
        requestToServer.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        // Specify that request is a HTTP post
        requestToServer.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        // Specify that the content type is a multipart request
        requestToServer.ContentType
            = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
        // Turn off keep alive
        requestToServer.KeepAlive = false;


        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string boundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "\r\n";
        byte[] boundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(boundaryStringLine);

        string lastBoundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "--\r\n";
        byte[] lastBoundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(lastBoundaryStringLine);

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("id", "TTR");


        // Get the byte array of the myFileDescription content disposition
        string myFileDescriptionContentDisposition = Java.Lang.String.Format(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}",
            "myFileDescription",
            "A sample file description");
        byte[] myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes
            = ascii.GetBytes(myFileDescriptionContentDisposition);

        string fileUrl = file;
        // Get the byte array of the string part of the myFile content
        // disposition
        string myFileContentDisposition = Java.Lang.String.Format(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"{0}\"; "
             + "filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
            "myFile", Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), Path.GetExtension(fileUrl));
        byte[] myFileContentDispositionBytes =
            ascii.GetBytes(myFileContentDisposition);

        var name = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUrl);

        // Calculate the total size of the HTTP request
        long totalRequestBodySize = boundaryStringLineBytes.Length * 2
            + lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length
            + myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length
            + myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length
            + fileInfo.Length;
        // And indicate the value as the HTTP request content length
        requestToServer.ContentLength = totalRequestBodySize;

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        // Write the http request body directly to the server
        using (Stream s = requestToServer.GetRequestStream())
        {
            //foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            //{
            //    s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            //    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            //    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            //    s.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

            //}
            // Send the file description content disposition over to the server
            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes, 0,
                myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length);

            // Send the file content disposition over to the server
            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileContentDispositionBytes, 0,
                myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length);

            // Send the file binaries over to the server, in 1024 bytes chunk
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } // end while

            fileStream.Close();

            // Send the last part of the HTTP request body
            s.Write(lastBoundaryStringLineBytes, 0, lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length);

            WebResponse response = requestToServer.GetResponse();

            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string replyFromServer = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            return replyFromServer;
        }
    }
```

The content-disposition values that are written on the client side aren't being retrieved on the server side. On the server side, the file name is read as "{0}" and subsequently other values are read as "{1}" and "{2}".

My server side code looks like so:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;


        var id = httpRequest.Form["{0}"];
        var id2 = httpRequest.Form[0];

        var s = id;
        var l = id2;

        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {

                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                // NOTE: To store in memory use postedFile.InputStream
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for 2 days and it's driving me crazy. I have chopped and changed my code several time but each time I have different issues. This is the closest I have come to making my code work except reading the headers properly on the server.

I will forever be grateful to the person the person who will help me out.

Comment: Why do you use Java.Lang.String.Format? Use .NET String.Format instead.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your response. That could potentially be the issue. I'll change that line and see if it works

Comment: that was indeed that issue. Can you please reply to my question so I can mark your answer as accepted? :)

Comment: There's one other issue. I'm hoping you can help me with it. httpRequest doesn't contain the contents of the varibale myFileDescriptionContentDisposition  but only the contains contents of myFileContentDisposition. How can I access the values of the first variable ?

Comment: With quick inspection of your code (which is not easy to follow by the way) cannot tell what can be the problem in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is most likely something like Android application. You use `Java.Lang.String.Format` there, and syntax of java format strings is different from .NET format strings, so your {0} {1} etc placesholders are not getting expanded. To fix, just use regular .NET `String.Format`.

Comment: Thank for provided the answer. It was definitely the issue in my code.